# Best Method to accept multiple external datafeed

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm in the middle of a project that I am working on. It's a classified website for lighting distributors created in php. I would like to accept csv data-feed from each distributor and import the data about 3 times a week. I would also like the data-feed to be hosted on the distributors website and I would import the data to the classified website mysql database from the external link that is provide by the distributor.

What would be the best method to import multiple data-feeds from multiple distributors? I am sorry that I have posted this question but I am desperate. I have search the net for answers but came up empty.

Would it be best to create a cron job that calls a script to import each feed? Obviously I would have a test database to first test each data-feed at first to make sure all the data in the csv file is the correct location.

Would I have to use the test database each and every time I import the data? What would be the best way to prevent something from happening to my database if for some reason the distributor changes the feed?

Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of ETL. While this question is a little too broad for SO, here's how I would go about it (from a high level):

1. Create a script to import the CSV to your local file system
2. Import the data from your local file system to a "Stage" table in your database
3. Check whatever you want to check (did it load without error, does the stage table look correct, etc)
4. Assuming everything checks out, drop and reload (or upsert or whatever) from your stage table to the live table. Consider adding a new field to your live tables that holds the timestamp from when the data was last loaded for that record
5. Consider archiving the flat file on your local system for preservation sake
6. Make a cron job to run your script that does the above steps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would I have to make a "Stage" DB for each distributor? If everything goes as plan I will have over 100 distributors.

Comment: That's up to you. One big ETL/Stage database, or many.. If it's all on the same MySQL server, then one database for stage would make sense, then when you drop and reload or merge up to the target table for each load it can go whereever it needs to.